# Git and VB6 - References Normalization

Tags: git, reference, com, vb6, normalization

VB6 Project files (`*.vbp`) store referenced `*.dll` and `*.ocx` GUIDs ie:

```
Reference=*\G{5F1C5FFC-C9D6-11D3-B573-00A04B03B18A}#1.0#0#..\SomeLib.dll#SomeLib 1.0 Type Library
Object={D27CDB6B-AE6D-11CF-96B8-444553540000}#1.0#0; SomeControls.ocx
```

Each time a developer breaks compatibility the recompiled libraries change their GUID and the updated GUIDs are stored on the project files that reference those libraries.

These are inocuous changes that introduce a lot of noise for a developer when checking which files should or shouldn't be included on a commit.

If I have regexp that normalizes the Project files references, how can I use it to make git ignore these differences on `git status` or `git diff` so that files are not uselessly updated?

Comment: If the COM object (dll or ocx) has not retained binary compatibility with the prior version, then updating the reference is not an innocuous change - it's required that you do so in order to instantiate and call the new dll or ocx.  A better question is why are the changes to the dll or ocx code frequently breaking compatibility? It's usually best practice to not change the interface for existing methods, properties and events; you can add new methods, properties and events in order to add new interfaces (eg: arguments) and retain binary compatibility with the previous version.

Comment: It's innocuous in the sense that the guids on developer machinnes won't match each other and neither will match production binnaries guids. They will be replaced anyway. We try to keep interfaces constant. But it's easier to break compatibility than to duplicate functions when, ie, function arguments need to be updated.

Comment: Everything you're saying is the exact reasons to not break compatibility. VB6 (really COM) doesn't support compile time overloading, but creating a new function with slightly different arguments is exactly that - overloading. It's not easier, in the big picture, to break compatibility. Maintaining compatibility with the existing interface means backward compatibility - the guids on your developer machine will match each other (for the legacy interface), and will match production (again, for legacy). Adding new functions (overloading) and maintaining compatibility will make you life easier.

Comment: We have a rule that no one may commit changes to VBP file references; reference changes may originate only from our build environment. If you can manage it that way then you could tell people to generally ignore all local changes to VBPs, unless you are adding / removing project files frequently.

Comment: @MarkL I think what he means is that during a development cycle bincomp changes a lot as they are adding/modifying features. I imagine that once they do a release then they have fixed the bincomp for that particular version. I don't think they would need backwards compatibility for the numerous development builds which just get tossed away anyhow.

Comment: It's as @DaveInCaz says. I wanted to automate that,  but teaching the development team to be careful  with the vbp files might work as well.

Comment: @xvan I can't recall specifically, but there might be some commit or push hooks you could use to restrict changes to VBPs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately I went he opposite way.
Instead of trying to make git ignore the changes, a merge-driver can be used to handle all the merging conflicts.

I built a small [vb6-merge-driver](https://github.com/xvan/vb6-merge-driver) that focuses on minimizing the amount of merging conflicts, resolving them with a "take-ours" strategy to preserve the GUIDs.

One should just be careful that merging the GUIDs aren't replaced on a merge ff.